# how to build rails server without network

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I will work on a ROR project next month, but the server has no network , the whole company has no public network, how can I run bundle install or rvm ? I haven’t use docker, is docker suitable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once RVM is installed, I don't think it needs any internet connection though.
For the `bundle install`, in your Gemfile, you can specify the source for your gems. By default, it's https://rubygems.org/, but nothing is preventing you to :

1. Run your own rubygems mirror on the side
2. Reference it in your app as the gem source.

See the full documentation here about these two points : http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/